# Smart contract copy

Tags: solidity, web3js, private-blockchain, quorum

So I am in a permissioned blockchain setup, using Quorum as a client.

I have deployed a private smart contract to members A and B, and now I have the need to redeploy it, giving access to member C.

Is there a way to copy the whole smart contract data and redeploy it? (Instead of "manually" querying all the data from the old contract and putting it in the new one.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently there's no way to extend a private contract to other parties (although this is on the Quorum/Tessera roadmap).
So at the moment, you would need to do it manually or within the contract itself by reading data from the old contract.